# How to use IOS5 Safari Reader Mode Layout in your own app

Tags: ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS access to Safari Reader feature through UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657553/ios-access-to-safari-reader-feature-through-uiwebview)

Its a wonderful layout. From fonts to paragraph properties. Is there a resource that I can obtain ios5 safari reader mode css layout?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean have an app that has a UIWebView and use reader mode. Looks like not right now:

[iOS access to Safari Reader feature through UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657553/ios-access-to-safari-reader-feature-through-uiwebview)